# how to test POODLE vulnerability for Jboss 7AS

Tags: java, security, jboss7.x, poodle-attack

We were facing the POODLE vulnerability in Jboss 7AS and I am able to provide a fix to the same issue.

By adding `protocol="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"` attribute to the `ssl` tag in `standalone.xml`.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466273/poodle-vulnerability-jboss-and-ie)

Now I didn't know how I can test it. Can someone please let me know the way to test it?

Comment: do anyone know how to do this??

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: @artbristol thanks... but actually I have a server locally... do you any thing about testing it locally.

Answer (score 1):

Try the nmap poodle detector

https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-poodle.html

From the summary

> Checks whether SSLv3 CBC ciphers are allowed (POODLE)
>
> Run with -sV to use Nmap's service scan to detect SSL/TLS on
>   non-standard ports. Otherwise, ssl-poodle will only run on ports that
>   are commonly used for SSL.
>
> POODLE is CVE-2014-3566. All implementations of SSLv3 that accept CBC
>   ciphersuites are vulnerable. For speed of detection, this script will
>   stop after the first CBC ciphersuite is discovered. If you want to
>   enumerate all CBC ciphersuites, you can use Nmap's own
>   ssl-enum-ciphers to do a full audit of your TLS ciphersuites.

Answer (score 0):

Poodle is a vulnerability that implicitly affects to SSLv3. Then for check it, you have a lot of ways to do it.

First way with [nmap](http://nmap.org/):

```
 $ nmap -sT -p443 --script ssl-poodle <target>
```

Second way with nmap:

```
 $ nmap -sT -p443 --script ssl-enum-ciphers <target>
```

If here you have SSLv3 ciphers then you are vulnerable.

Other way, with sslscan:

```
$ sslscan <domain>
```

Other way, with [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/):

```
$ openssl s_client -ssl3 -connect host:port
```

If connect, you are vulnerable

Other way, using [SSL Test Server](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) of Qualys.

And in Java, you can try to connect SSLv3, if the server accept your connection, then you are vulnerable.

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3");
```

Set the protocol SSLv3 before the connection.